# Bootstrap 3 - Responsive Login Dialog

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, templates, authentication, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to work out a login module that looks like this
[image: Login Screen]

I've tried looking for bootstrap templates that allow this but I can't find any available. I was wondering if anyone here knows any bootstrap templates that does:

- Responsive Login Dialog Box w/ Logo
- Darkens the background

Been going nuts over this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can do a modal box with the classes: modal, hide. And splitting modal box content in three different sections if you want: header, body and footer.

```
<div class="modal hide" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
        <h3>Login to MyWebsite.com</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post" action='' name="login_form">
          <p><input type="text" class="span3" name="eid" id="email" placeholder="Email"></p>
          <p><input type="password" class="span3" name="passwd" placeholder="Password"></p>
          <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
            <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
          </p>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        New To MyWebsite.com?
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Register</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

For details you can check out:
[Login form in modal](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/login-form-in-a-modal)

Answer (score 2):

There are ways around using any JS if you would prefer although you can take the modal approach. here is another suggestion.

Here is a Bootly of a similar solution

## http://www.bootply.com/SeRZCS7L09

you can use the twitter bootstrap 3 for this. Because you can specify the width in your own CSS and then use the grid system to supply the rest. Have a look through the get started section o bootstrap 3.

if i was going to make this i would do the following:

HTML skipped the labels etc juut a brief example

```
<body>
    <div id="login-form">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password/>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username/>
    </div>
</body>
```

Link my Bootstrap to get the benefits of form-control

then in my CSS sheet:

```
#login-form{
    width: 400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    //etc etc etc
}
```

This is very basic but i feel there is no need to repeat to much as you will be able to look through the bootstrap documentation and it shows you in depth how to use the grids/columns/rows etc. using these you can easily create that look!  i use it for a lot of projects.

[Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/)

the darkened background could be achieved by a div with black background with maybe half opacity or less, you would make this appear via transition or JS. [CSS3 Opacity](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp)